# How to edit data of dynamically created form in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am new to Angular developmet.In my project,I have a form with dynamically add and remove input box using Add and Remove button in Angular 8 Application. After submitting the form,i want to display and edit the input fields with the same add and remove button. How can i achieve the functionality in edit.

I share the stackblitz url of creating a dynamic form with add and remove button.I need the same form for edit. Can anyone help me to give solution?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-fields-y2ijvu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I mean the form Inputs are editable right now and their editable after Submit (as per your example on StackBlitz).

Comment: I have 2 form, one is new another is edit form.Both are in different pages..Once you fill the new form you hit submit button.Here you can add the input box as much you want and submit (i.e) the stackblitz soln. The data here stored in a json format.I have another page, where we patch the json data in the edit form and we can add or remove input field if we want and then submit the updated data in edit form.

Comment: So if I get this correctly. You want to fill a form and submit in `AppComponent` but then afterwards you want to edit same submitted data in another component? Then I don't see the part where you have the other component or data transfer in your example StackBlitz. Please include that part too so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In order to populate the phones with dynamically received values (eg from api), you would need to add a parameter to `addPhone()` and call it when iterating over the received values.

```
  addPhone(phone: string): void {
    (this.userForm.get('phones') as FormArray).push(phone);
  }
```

`receivedPhones.forEach(phone => this.addPhone(phone))`

or you could `.setValue()` or `.patchValue()` of the FormArray like so:

`this.userForm.get('phones').setValue(receivedPhones)`

(`setValue()` requires that the array has equal member count)

It is possible to share one form for edit and view situations, just add a flag `isNew` and populate it, and use it. Oftentimes, the edit functionality resides at a different route (.../edit) which enables you to provide `isNew: true` on the route's `data` definition.